# Code editor with multiple categories of opened tabbed files?

Tags: ide, editor

Hi can anyone recommend a good, and ideally free editor that will allow me to group opened files based on a module or component I'm working on?

I'm learning joomla so I need one with php,JavaScript,HTML.

I'm currently using dreamweaver. It's great but I hate having to traverse through the file tabs which are usually hidden because I have so many files opened at once. I would ideally want something that will allow me to group these opened files almost like a folder structure where I can create a category for grouping the opened files together so as keep things that are related to one another close by.

Failing this please recommend what is the best approach when dealing with lots and lots of opened files.

I like how browser works because it allows me to open multiple instances and let me group the sites I want via tabs to each browser instance. Dreamweaver won't allow more than one instance. Is there anything out there that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UltraEdit gives tab a different color depending on the filetype - CSS are green, Javascript are orange, etc. I find this very useful. It also allows the tabs to spill over to several rows, instead of forcing them to one line like Dreamweaver.

If you do have to use Dreamweaver, you can use the file directory panel to traverse the folders on your hard disk. Double-click on a file in a subdirectory to open it, or switch to its tab if it is already open. The file directory panel is on the top-right by default, I think.